# MS Exchange with Default Email App is Randomly Draining Battery!

Tags: email, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s, exchange, battery-life

I'm using my Exchange email account for work with the default Email app on my Nexus S running Jellybean... usually everything works just fine, but within a week or so it'll start consuming massive amounts of battery.

Flushing the data + cache and deleting / reinstalling the Exchange account usually fixes whatever went awry... until the next time the problem comes back.

I haven't tried uninstalling / reinstalling the Email app itself, as the OS cautions me not to do that with a default app.

Is there a way to fix this problem besides "Don't Use It"?

Comment: You can install [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats) from Sven Knispel (if you cannot afford it, look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809)). You get some more insights and can spot some problems with it; the latter link also has a howto and some explanations. Some features require root though. Alternatively you can switch off sync for the exchange account (also programmatically/scheduled with [JuiceDefender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender)).